# Java JRE on ubuntu

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

A few quick question.  Does ubuntu server 16.04 LTS support Java 7? How do I check if it is installed?  When i do `java -version` it just says:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I'm not sure, but I don't see the JRE or a 7 on there.  Not sure if the JRE is needed for running game servers (ex. Minecraft, BungeeCord for Minecraft, etc...).  I think I have the JDK 8 installed which is fine.  I just need to know how to get the jre on my server.

Sorry if I seem a bit confused about what I need. I'm really lost.

Comment: You already have OpenJDK JRE installed. Do you have a special reason to use Java 7 instead of 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is currently using openjdk - which is a free,open and is in the ubuntu repository. JRE 7 you are talking about is the Oracle Java Runtime Environment which doesn't comes in ubuntu repository. You need to manually install JRE 7 and activate it system wide to use it. For developement and most cases everyone prefer to use Oracle Java rather than openJDK whilst the basic idea of both is to provide a suitable java environment. To install and activate oracle Java 7 you can do the following.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: So if I wanted to get the better version of the JDK do I need to just type these commands?

Comment: @joeldesante You already have OpenJDK 8, which should give you everything you need (A JDK includes the JRE, and Java 8 will run Java 7 things, and it's always good to run the latest version, which will give you security and performance benefits). You probably don't need the oracle Java though, but if you do, I'd recommend getting `oracle-java8-installer` instead.